# How to store command with option on variable of a function in zsh?

Tags: zsh, variable, function

I'm trying to learn bash scripting using [freeCodeCamp tutorial for beginners on YouTube](https://youtu.be/tK9Oc6AEnR4?t=2320).

I'm stuck at the point where he shows how to create a function.
He saved on a variable a command with an option

```
#!/bin/bash

showuptime(){
    up=$(uptime -p | cut -c4-)
    since=$(uptime -s)
    cat << EOF

----------
This machine has been up for ${up}
It has been running since ${since}
----------

EOF
}

showuptime
```

I'm not able to replicate on my MacBook M1 with zsh on terminal.

I'm using `#!/bin/zsh`
and It works only if I don't pass the -p and -s options.

Error:

```
uptime: illegal option -- p
usage: uptime
uptime: illegal option -- s
usage: uptime
```

Comment: hint: most of us can read your code better if you just copy and paste the code – instead of pasting a screenshot. None of us can copy and paste an image to try ourselves. Your "Error:" section already shows you know how to format code in questions! So, **please replace your picture of code with the actual code**.

Comment: Also, `uptime` is pretty operating system specific. I'm by no means an expert on Mac OS, but I think it's thoroughly possible that the `uptime` command you have has nothing to do with the one that the youtube video assumes you have (probably Linux?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear a few things up:

- As variable *of* a function you would rather indicate the arguments passed to the function (none here) which are accessed via `$1`, `$2`, and so on.
- What you have are variables *in* your functions and because they are not marked `local` they are not even limited to the function.
- The `$( )` construct is called [command substitution](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution). It does not store the command in any way but instead executes what is inside it (`uptime -p | cut -c4-` in your first case) and assigns the output the command produced to the variable. The `uptime` command is executed at this point. The command output is stored, not the command.
- As Marcus mentioned the error comes from the `uptime` command not supporting those options. Since Mac OS is related to BSD the FreeBSD [man page for `uptime`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?uptime) can give an orientation. On FreeBSD `uptime` accepts no options at all and it is probably the same for Mac OS.
- To answer the question title: the best way to store a command with options is to use an array. `my_stored_command=(ls -lt --human-readable /home)` can then later be run as `"${my_stored_command[@]}"` which expands the array to its individual elements again forming a command invocation.